# Test whether sum of two integers might overflow

Tags: c

From C traps and pitfalls

> If a and b are two integer variables, known to be non-negative then to
>   test whether `a+b` might overflow use:
>
> ```
>      if ((int) ((unsigned) a + (unsigned) b) < 0 )
>         complain();
> ```

I didn't get that how comparing the sum of both integers with zero will let you know that there is an overflow?

Comment: The answer you accepted is wrong...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to detect integer overflow in C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/best-way-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c)

Comment: ^This was asked ~2 years ago

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The code you saw for testing for overflow is just bogus.

For signed integers, you must test like this:

```
if ((a^b) < 0) overflow=0; /* opposite signs can't overflow */
else if (a>0) overflow=(b>INT_MAX-a);
else overflow=(b<INT_MIN-a);
```

Note that the cases can be simplified a lot if one of the two numbers is a constant.

For unsigned integers, you can test like this:

```
overflow = (a+b<a);
```

This is possible because unsigned arithmetic is defined to wrap, unlike signed arithmetic which invokes undefined behavior on overflow.

Comment: Don't you have to special case when `a` is `INT_MIN` and `-INT_MIN` is an overflow?

Comment: @Jens: Why? `a` is never negated. You're testing to see if `a+b` will overflow. If `a` is positive, `INT_MAX-a` cannot overflow. If `a` is negative or zero, `INT_MIN-a` cannot overflow.

Comment: right, somehow I always thought of `a-b` as `a + (-b)` but which in this case, isn't.

Comment: `*Nod*`, if that were the case though then you could never subtract `INT_MAX` from anything. :-)

Comment: a^b < 0 should be (a^b) < 0 as < has higher priority than ^

Answer (score 2):

When an overflow occurs, the sum exceeds some range (let's say this one):

```
-4,294,967,295 < sum < 4,294,967,295
```

So when the sum overflows, it wraps around and goes back to the beginning:

```
4,294,967,295 + 1 = -4,294,967,295
```

If the sum is negative and you *know* the the two numbers are positive, then the sum overflowed.

Comment: BTW, that's assuming your integers are unsigned. Read the Wikipedia article (yes, one exists...) on them: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

Comment: If your integers are unsigned, the sum is never "negative"... This is not a valid test.

Answer (score 2):

If a and b are known to be non negative integers, the sequence (int) ((unsigned) a + (unsigned) b) will return indeed a negative number on overflow.

Lets assume a 4 bit (max positive integer is 7 and max unsigned integer is 15) system with the following values:

```
a = 6

b = 4

a + b = 10 (overflow if performed with integers)
```

While if we do the addition using the unsigned conversion, we will have:

```
int((unsigned)a + (unsigned)b) = (int) ((unsigned)(10)) = -6
```

To understand why, we can quickly check the binary addition:

```
a = 0110 ; b = 0100 - first bit is the sign bit for signed int.

0110 +
0100
------
1010
```

`For unsigned int, 1010 = 10`. While the same representation `in signed int means -6`.

So the `result` of the operation is indeed `< 0`.

Answer (score 1):

If the integers are unsigned and you're assuming IA32, you can do some inline assembly to check the value of the CF flag. The asm can be trimmed a bit, I know.

```
int of(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
        unsigned int c;

        __asm__("addl %1,%2\n"
                "pushfl \n"
                "popl %%edx\n"
                "movl %%edx,%0\n"
                :"=r"(c)
                :"r"(a), "r"(b));

        return(c&1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some good explanations on [this page](http://www.fefe.de/intof.html).

Here's the simple way from that page that I like:

```
Do the addition normally, then check the result (e.g. if (a+23<23) overflow).
```

Comment: That may sometimes work in practice, but the behavior of signed overflow is undefined.  Even if the hardware has the typical 2's-complement behavior, an optimizing compiler is likely to *assume* that no overflow occurs (because if it does, any possible behavior is valid anyway).  For example, the expression `(a+23<23)` could easily be optimized to just `1`.

Answer (score 0):

As we know that Addition of 2 Numbers might be overflow.
So for that we can use following way to add the two numbers.

Adder Concept

Suppose we have 2 numbers "a" AND "b"

(a^b)+(a&b);
this equation will give the correct result..
And this is patented by the Samsung.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? It gives 1 for sum of 1 and 1: `(1^1) + (1&1) == 1`

Answer (score 0):

assuming twos compliment representation and 8 bit integers, the most significant bit has sign (1 for negative and 0 for positive), since we know the integers are non negative, it means most significant bit is 0 for both integers. Now if adding the unsigned representation of these numbers result in a 1 in most significant bit then that mean the addition has overflowed, and to check whether an unsigned integer has a 1 in most significant bit is to check if it is more than the range of signed integer, or you can convert it to signed integer which will be negative (because the most significant bit is 1)

example 8 bit signed integers (range -128 to 127):

```
twos compliment of 127 = 0111 1111
twos complement of 1   = 0000 0001

unsigned 127           = 0111 1111
unsigned 1             = 0000 0001
unsigned sum           = 1000 0000
```

sum is 128, which is not a overflow for unsigned integer but is a overflow for signed integer, the most significant bit gives it away.